# how to wrap an iframe to make it larger

Tags: iframe

I use an iframe that is currently 642px x 460px. I have embedded the iframe to my site but can not change the size of the iframe to 920px x 560px. Just wondering if there is some type of "wrapper" I can use to override the size this iframe is fixed on.

Source - http://wiz1.net/channel5?61612516

Iframe - src="http://www.wiz1.net/ch5" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="no" frameborder="0" width="642" height="460">

Thanks 
Marty

Comment: Can't you just change width="642" height="460" to desired size?

Comment: no, I have tried that.

Comment: Can you post more of your HTML? At least the div inside which the iframe is?

Comment: i just add that iframe to my wordpress site and it spits out the video

Answer (score 0):

In the Iframe snippet you have Width and Height defined. Just change them to desired values.

```
<iframe src="http://www.wiz1.net/ch5" 
    scrolling="no"
    allowtransparency="no"
    frameborder="0"
    width="DESIRED_WIDTH" height="DESIRED_HEIGHT">
</iframe>
```